# Livestatus doesnt work with Nagios on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, nagios

Im trying to use livestatus with nagios on FreeBSD.
I've managed to compile and configure it, but Nagios doesnt seem to be loading the module and dont produce any errors.

Other info:

```
$ grep broker nagios.cfg
event_broker_options=-1
broker_module=/usr/local/lib/npcdmod.o config_file=/usr/local/etc/pnp/npcd.cfg
broker_module=/usr/local/lib/mk-livestatus/livestatus.o /var/spool/nagios/rw/live

$ ls -lah /usr/local/lib/mk-livestatus
total 664
drwxr-xr-x   2 root    wheel    512B Apr 16 14:58 .
drwxr-xr-x  23 root    wheel     11k Apr 16 14:58 ..
-r-xr-xr-x   1 nagios  nagios   593k Apr 16 14:58 livestatus.o
-r-xr-xr-x   1 nagios  nagios   7.2k Apr 16 14:58 unixcat

$ ls -lah /var/spool/nagios/rw
total 8
drwxrwsr-x  2 nagios  www      512B Apr 16 15:26 .
drwxrwxr-x  7 nagios  nagios   512B Apr 16 15:26 ..
prw-rw----  1 nagios  www        0B Apr 16 15:26 nagios.cmd

$ tail -f /var/spool/nagios/nagios.log &
$ sudo service nagios restart
Performing sanity check of nagios configuration: 
OK
Stopping nagios.
Waiting for PIDS: 42763[1334575860] Caught SIGTERM, shutting down...
[1334575860] Successfully shutdown... (PID=42763)
.
Performing sanity check of nagios configuration: OK
Starting nagios.
[1334575862] Nagios 3.3.1 starting... (PID=49676)
[1334575862] Local time is Mon Apr 16 15:31:02 MSK 2012
[1334575862] LOG VERSION: 2.0
[1334575864] Finished daemonizing... (New PID=49677)
```

As you can see in nagios.cfg, i also use PNP with broker module, and it work fine.

Comment: crank up the debug level, and see what shows up in the debug file

Comment: Keith, there is nothing related to livestatus even on maximum verbosity, and maximum log level

Comment: what did you set debug_level to?

Comment: Keith, debug_level = 255

Comment: That is not anywhere near "maximum" debug level, but it is enough to cover broker stuff, *if* it was going to produce any debug output...

-1 would be "everything" (equivalent to 4095, iirc)

Comment: Could you please show us a snippet of `nagios.log` or `nagios.debug` when restarting? Have you tried doing automatic setup instead of manual setup?